# Displaying single Instagram images as a tile

Tags: plugins, images

The Instagram shortcode is great for displaying a single, specific Instagram image: https://en.support.wordpress.com/instagram/instagram-images/

Problem is that I need to display the image as a tile, so how do I do that?

i.e. for example something like this `[instagram url=LINK width=320 format=tile]` where LINK is the url of the specific Instagram image.

I can find lots of plugins that shows tile carousels and tile grids, but I just need to show specific single images as tiles.

Anyone know of a plugin or a bit of code for doing this?

Thanks,
Mads

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by applying following count to api :

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ID-GOES-HERE/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN-GOES-HERE&count=1
```

Hope it helps..